# Is it normal for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole to return an empty set when there are user roles?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, .net-4.0, asp.net-identity

I am trying to return a list of `ApplicationUser` which belongs to different `IdentityRole` and those that also do not belong to any role.

So when I did my testing I noticed that the following statement gave me all the users in the system.

```
UserManager.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).Where(u => u.Roles.Count == 0);
```

To me the statement should mean that if there are no roles to the user, it should return it as part of the set but apparently on debugging, all the users return a count of 0.

If I were to use the appropriate RoleManager for if a user belongs to the role or not, I get the correct answer:

```
UserManager.IsInRole(applicationUser.Id, "Administrator");
```

So I am trying to figure out if it is normal for it to return an empty set.

Also within my database, the `aspnetuserroles` table the foreign key to the `identityusers` seems to be pointing to the wrong column or the code is updating to the wrong column.
The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `aspnetuserroles` (
  `UserId` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `RoleId` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `IdentityUser_Id` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`,`RoleId`),
  KEY `IdentityRole_Users` (`RoleId`),
  KEY `IdentityUser_Id` (`IdentityUser_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `IdentityRole_Users` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `aspnetroles` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `IdentityUser_Roles` FOREIGN KEY (`IdentityUser_Id`) REFERENCES `identityusers` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The `UserId` column has all the correct User Ids but is not referenced.
The `IdentityUser_Id` column is all null and is referenced for some reason.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little testing and found that when using

```
UserManager.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).Where(u => u.Roles.Count == 0);
```

I was also getting 0 results even though I know for sure it shouldn't have been. So, I decided to look at what was going on in the debugger. It was actually erroring, but I didn't know it without looking at the debugger. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to get, but by throwing a ToList() on the end like so

```
UserManager.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).Where(u => u.Roles.Count == 0).ToList();
```

I started getting expected results. Hopefully it works for you, too! Also, using the following netted me all the same results. Good luck!

```
UserManager.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Count == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: I was trying to pass it as an IEnumerable for one of my views from the IQueryable. I'll go try the ToList method.